# Pass Value to javascript from listview layout template

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Want to pass listview item value to javascript function ,this control is inside layout template i.e anchor tag .I am binding data to this anchor tag and want to call the javascripot function on this click.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListviewInnerComent" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID"                                                               OnItemDataBound="ListviewInnerComent_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="ListviewInnerComent_ItemCommand">
    <LayoutTemplate>

     <ul id="itemPlaceholderContainer"runat="server">
       <li  id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">

         </li></ul>

<div >
 <a href='<%# Eval("ID") %>' id="showmore"  class="showmore"  runat="server" onclick="GetRecords1();" >Show More</a>

//WANT TO PASS THIS ANCHOR TAG VALUE  THAT i AM BINDING TO JAVASCRIPT FINCTION. 
                                                                                 </div>


                                                                    </LayoutTemplate>


function GetRecords1
(response) {
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
        var xml = $(xmlDoc);

    var ID=document.getElementById("showmore").title; 
alert(ID);
WANT TO CALL PASSED VALUE HERE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
<a href="#" class="showmore"
  onclick="GetRecords1('<%# Eval("ID") %>');return false;">Show More</a>
```

The **href="#"** ensures some browsers like IE will handle the  element as a link. The **return false;** prevents the web browser following the link after the js function is run.

I've removed the **id** and **runat** attributes since these aren't required -- this doesn't need to be a server control.

Comment: It's not working inside Listview Insert ItemTemplate/Layout Template .  This Id is not binding with Anchor Tag. Is there any option to show anchor tag single time for number of row's. For Example if we put anchortag inside ItemTemplate , anchor tag will show untill it has data (n no of rows), But I want to show It single time . How It can be possible.